# Copying of a cell value from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

Team,

Am new to excel Macro and trying to copy a value of a Cell E15 from a workbook name september to D15 of another workbook name format and am unable to do that with the below coding.
Please help me

I used the below coding to do so.

```
Sub COPYCELL()
Dim wbk As Workbook
strFirstFile = "c:\documents and Settings\msivas\Desktop\James\September.xls"
strSecondFile = "c:\documents and Settings\msivas\Desktop\James\Format.xls"
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
With wbk.Sheets("Summary")
Range("E15").Copy
End With
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
With wbk.Sheets("sheet1")
Range("D12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
End With
End Sub
```

Am receiving an error and unable to know.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` forces you to declare your variables. I would define your file locations as strings, use seperate variables for the containing and destination workbooks and if you use `With` you need to place a `.` in front of any lines e.g. `.range("E15").Copy`

Comment: AM Receiving an stating "Error 400 "

Answer (score 3):

try this update. By not recycling the wbk variable, you will avoid issues.

```
Sub COPYCELL()
Dim wbkOrg As Workbook, wbkDest as workbook
dim strFirstFile as string, strSecondFile as string

strFirstFile = "c:\documents and Settings\msivas\Desktop\James\September.xls"
strSecondFile = "c:\documents and Settings\msivas\Desktop\James\Format.xls"

Set wbkOrg = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
Set wbkDest = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)

wbkOrg.Sheets("Summary").Range("E15").Copy wbkDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("D12")

End Sub
```

Comment: After using the updated code it is not showing any error and where as the destination column is being empty and the cursor is being shown in the E15 column itself.

Comment: What do you have in wbkOrg.Sheets("Summary").Range("E15") ? If you don't have anything, nothing will copy to D12.

Comment: there is a data like 5000 in range E15 in summary sheet

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, this works for me:

```
Option Explicit
Sub COPYCELL()
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
    Dim strFirstfile As String, strSecondFile As String

strFirstfile = "c:\documents and Settings\msivas\Desktop\James\September.xls"
strSecondFile = "c:\documents and Settings\msivas\Desktop\James\Format.xls"

    Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(strFirstfile)

    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)

    With wbk1.Sheets("Summary")
        .Range("E15").Copy
    End With

    With wbk2.Sheets("sheet1")
        .Range("D12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The Destination column is being blank and the data is not being displayed and nor even a error after using the above code

Comment: what is in the original cell that is being copied?

Comment: Try using `xlPasteValues` instead of `xlPasteAll`, does that make a difference? If that does nothing enter some plain text in the cell and see if it is copied?